# Non-Changing Determinant When Adding (Seemingly) Arbitrary Entries

Tags: determinant

**Question:**

I've found that adding what seem to be arbitrary values in the 4th row don't change the value of the determinant. Why is that?

A = $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

B = $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & -12 & 7 & 14 & 41 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace those entries by unknowns, say $a,b,c,d$, then calculate the determinant by expanding along the first column.  See what you get.

Comment: I see! The variables are 0'd out by the Laplace expansion.

Comment: Your question was important in me finding my answer, but it did not answer my question for me. Should I still accept your answer?

Comment: @jackskis It's up to you.  Some people don't like "hint" answers, others do - you can in fact find lots of debate about this on the "meta" pages.  Personally, if I ask a question and somebody gives a hint which enables me to answer it, I will always upvote it and usually accept it.  But it's entirely your decision.

Comment: Alright. I am just trying to adhere to community standards. I will accept it.